# How to use `react-textarea-code-editor` with Remix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

i'm getting this error below when loading the root of my web app.  `react-textarea-code-editor` is on a separate route.

and i'm getting this same error after following the advice here: https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/pages/gotchas#importing-esm-packages

that is, adding `react-textarea-code-editor`to the `serverDependenciesToBundle` option in  `remix.config.js` didn't help. same error.

any suggestions on how to get this working would be wonderful

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/rehype/index.js from /Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/api/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of /Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/rehype/index.js in /Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/api/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at node_modules/@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor/cjs/utils.js (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/api/index.js:819:118)
    at /Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/api/index.js:7:50
    at node_modules/@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor/cjs/index.js (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/api/index.js:1058:362)
    at /Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/api/index.js:7:50
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/api/index.js:17853:49)
    at /Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/@remix-run/serve/dist/index.js:43:17
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at next (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:140:7)
    at next (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:140:7)
    at next (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:140:7)
    at next (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:140:7)
    at next (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:140:7)
    at next (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:140:7)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at param (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at param (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:376:14)
    at Function.process_params (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:421:3)
    at next (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at logger (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/morgan/index.js:144:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
    at /Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
    at SendStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/send/index.js:270:17)
    at SendStream.onStatError (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/send/index.js:417:12)
    at next (/Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/send/index.js:759:28)
    at /Users/stuartrobinson/repos/mailpotato/frontend/mk-remix-supabase-public-demo/node_modules/send/index.js:767:23
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:190:21)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the text editor to load, but it appears to be broken, but I'll leave that to you.

Remix doesn't support ESM on the server. Typically you would use the `serverDependenciesToBundle` prop to have Remix convert these to CJS. However, since it doesn't appear that the text editor works well with SSR, we can skip all that and use a dynamic `import` and wrap it in `<Suspense/>`

```
const CodeEditor = React.lazy(() => import('@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor'));

export default function Index() {
  const [code, setCode] = React.useState(
    `function add(a, b) {\n  return a + b;\n}`
  );

  return (
    <Suspense>
      <CodeEditor
        value={code}
        language="js"
        placeholder="Please enter JS code."
        onChange={(evn) => setCode(evn.target.value)}
        padding={15}
        style={{
          fontSize: 12,
          backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
          fontFamily:
            'ui-monospace,SFMono-Regular,SF Mono,Consolas,Liberation Mono,Menlo,monospace',
        }}
      />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

StackBlitz ⚡️ https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-klidyj?file=app/routes/index.tsx

I updated *tsconfig.json* as well to support dynamic imports:

```json
{
  "target": "ES2020",
  "module": "ES2020",
}
```